# PHP convert Latin intro Greek characters

Tags: php, string

Is it possible to convert Latin char into Greek?

example:

```
$string = 'OMEGA';
```

result:

```
$string = 'ΩΜΕΓΑ';
```

Comment: What would happen when you encounter a `K` which can be translittered as both `Χ` and `Κ`? I'm not sure there's an easy way to transliterate correctly from Latin to Greek.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not easy way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, because only str_replace will not work with non utf-8 chars.

```
if (!function_exists('mb_str_replace')) {
   function mb_str_replace($search, $replace, $subject, &$count = 0)
   {
       if (!is_array($subject)) {
           $searches = is_array($search) ? array_values($search) : [$search];
           $replacements = is_array($replace) ? array_values($replace) : [$replace];
           $replacements = array_pad($replacements, count($searches), '');
           foreach ($searches as $key => $search) {
               $parts = mb_split(preg_quote($search), $subject);
               $count += count($parts) - 1;
               $subject = implode($replacements[$key], $parts);
           }
       } else {
           foreach ($subject as $key => $value) {
               $subject[$key] = mb_str_replace($search, $replace, $value, $count);
           }
       }
       return $subject;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you were able to set the transliterations yourself then you could just use `str_replace`. Here is an example:

```
$english = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J');
$greek = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j');

echo str_replace($english, $greek, "HELLO");
```

So, in my example A is replaced with a, B with b, C with c and so on. Any letter after J in the alphabet will remain unchanged. You could adjust this so O becomes Ω and so on ...

Comment: about this way i know , but i thought there is better way